# Loop function for multiple Data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, automation

I am trying to create a for loop to cycle through multiple data frames doing the same thing for each set. Below is an example of what I am trying to do but I get the error:

Error

```
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

generating code

```
for (k in 1:6) {
  get(paste0("df.",k))$YrQtr <- paste0(format(Sys.Date()-months(1),format="%Y"),quarters((Sys.Date()-months(1))))
      get(paste0("df.",k))$SetID <- k
}
```

Comment: Please use `dput()` or `dput(head())` to post a copy of your data to make your issue reproducible. And it's better if you post the script part of your question using the code block function. Thanks

Comment: Why not create a list of data frames use the relevant apply function?

Comment: list of frames: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227, then use `lapply` (or `Map`)